# Importance of a Node in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph with n nodes, where each of the nodes has a value. The node value may also be called as a weight in this case(note that I am assigning a weight to the node and not the edge), then given a node 'a' in the graph, is it possible to compute any metric/measure which tells me the 'importance' of the node in the graph?

I am not sure whether [Centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) is what i am looking at. I think Centrality is more related to the degree of the node; whereas I am looking at how a 'important' node is from the other important nodes(which are calculated using weights) in the graph.

Just to expatiate on my Q(and taking a slightly different view) : Assume a graph which initially has no weights/value assigned for any of the nodes. Now, i identify a few nodes and assign a weight/value 1 to them. Now, given a node(which has not been assigned a weight/value), i want to calculate its weight/value, based on its 'weighted' distance from each of the other nodes(which have been assigned weights). You can probably take the distance as the number of edges and multiple it by a weighting factor to calculate the weight/value of a node.

Comment: It's hard to answer if you yourself don't know how you define importance...

Comment: You may want to check out the sister-site http://math.stackexchange.com/ as a place where you might get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Eigenvector centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Eigenvector_centrality)? From Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> Eigenvector centrality is a measure of
>   the **importance of a node** in a network.
>   It assigns relative scores to all
>   nodes in the network based on the
>   principle that **connections to
>   high-scoring nodes contribute more to
>   the score of the node** in question than
>   equal connections to low-scoring
>   nodes.